# How to generate documentation for enum members when generating TypeScript definitions from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

Following the official instructions in [Creating .d.ts Files from .js files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html), I am trying to generate definitions for a JSDoc `@enum`.

```js
/**
 * The direction enum.
 * 
 * @enum {number}
 */
const Direction = {
  /**
   * Up direction.
   * 
   * @type {number}
   * @constant
   */
  Up: 1,
  /**
   * Down direction.
   * 
   * @type {number}
   * @constant
   */
  Down: 2,
  /**
   * Left direction.
   * 
   * @type {number}
   * @constant
   */
  Left: 3,
  /**
   * Right direction.
   * 
   * @type {number}
   * @constant
   */
  Right: 4,
};
export default Direction;
```

For my `tsconfig.json`, I made sure that `removeComments` is set to `false`. I expect to see all the documentation for all the properties of the `Direction` object to carry over to the `.d.ts` file, however, I see the following output:

```
export default Direction;
/**
 * The direction enum.
 */
type Direction = number;
declare namespace Direction {
    const Up: number;
    const Down: number;
    const Left: number;
    const Right: number;
}
```

You can try it for yourself on the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&module=6&stripInternal=false&filetype=js&removeComments=false#code/LAKA9AVBoAQTAVAFgUxgEwJYCcUGMAXTAewDsYVSBXAWwDpZ5GYABS2mAb2poCMVsAX0ZhQeMgGcCMACI58RMjAC8XWDEjQQMHfACqABwzzCJUg226Y6uKwIBPA2m61+Qm-BbjSUgIakCD1ZcX3QyABt7D1FLQwAuGABGABp1TSCZYgB3cixcUzILHVsglgcnLh43YUtbL0kCf0DazxCw0kjo9UychIAmVMt0lpgAGRQAM2k8hTMiq1Ly5yqBGuLPbz8A0raIqJaYnXGphIBmQZ1h9ZgAJUwAcyRpk0VzIMXHZddV0s3G7ZGLF2HX260OtweTwSABZBoIANygFAADwMxGw00mvio4Wkcnyr0RICAA). How can I ensure that all the documentation properly carries over?

Comment: Not that this fixes anything, but that playground link has `removeComments` as `true`, not `false`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @jcalz. Link has been updated.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488644/1048572) an alternative method of documenting enums with jsdoc is suggested

Comment: I would suggest you just file a bug report for the missing doc comments. However, notice that [*`@enum` is quite different from, and much simpler than, TypeScript’s `enum`*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#enum) (also [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30624)), and you can see that it's generating a `namespace` declaration not an enum.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use javascript with type annotations in comments instead of just writing typescript?

Comment: @Bergi In cases of existing libraries, generating TypeScript definitions to support TypeScript users is easier than porting everything to TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could use both `@typedef` and `@property` tags.

I can't see why we'd add `@readonly`, though, since TypeScript constants already represent variables whose values cannot be modified and the `Direction` object literal, as it is currently defined, it's not truly `readonly`.

Take the definition below as an example:

```js
/**
* @typedef Direction
* @property {number} Up "Up direction"  
* @property {number} Down "Down direction" 
* @property {number} Left "Left direction" 
* @property {number} Right "Right direction"
*/
const Direction = {
  Up: 1,
  Down: 2,
  Left: 3,
  Right: 4,
};
export default Direction;
```

Would generate the following `.d.ts` file:

```
export default Direction;
export type Direction = {
    /**
     * "Up direction"
     */
    Up: number;
    /**
     * "Down direction"
     */
    Down: number;
    /**
     * "Left direction"
     */
    Left: number;
    /**
     * "Right direction"
     */
    Right: number;
};
declare namespace Direction {
    const Up: number;
    const Down: number;
    const Left: number;
    const Right: number;
}
```

Would that work for your use case?

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Moa. This comes close, but it seems like this is just a missing feature of `tsc` at the moment. But I think anyone else running into this issue would probably find this a satisfactory workaround.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely a missing feature of `tsc`. Glad to help.